# CakePHP 3: Allow access only when being redirected from a specific action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Good Morning, I'm trying to allow access to an controller only if the user is redirected from an other controller.

```php
if ($this->referer() != 
  Router::url(array(
    'controller'=>'customers', 'action'=>'register'
  ))) {
  return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'customers','action'=>'register']);
}
```

But the above snippet always redirects me to customers/register.

I could not find anything in CakePHP documentation, so if anyone has an idea for me?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->referer()` returns an URL, e.g. `http://foo.localhost/controller/action`, while `Router::url` returns a route only, e.g. `/controller/action`.

Thus your condition does not match.